# Difference between =(1+A$2)*B2 and =(1+$A$2)*B2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to find out if these two formulas are giving different results, and to explain why. I have tested both of them, and I think the results are the same, but I don't know why is that. Can anyone give me an explanation?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/785302/what-does-the-dollar-sign-mean-in-cell-references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They'll give different results if you copy or move the cell to another location. In the first, the `A` (with no `$` prefix) is a *relative* column, meaning copying or moving the cell contents to a different column will affect it.

By that, I mean moving the content from (for example) `X42` to `Y42` will result in the changed formula `(1+B$2)*C2`. Note *both* unprefixed columns have increased.

In the second, `$A` is an *absolute* column that will not change regardless of where you copy/move the cell contents to. The same move/copy alluded to in the previous paragraph would result in the formula `(1+$A$2)*C2` (the prefixed `$A` remains unchanged, the unprefixed `B` goes to `C`).

If you want to know *why* this is the case, have a look at the brilliant [You suck at Excel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nbkaYsR94c) by Joel Spolsky (slightly grating but at least humorously so, and definitely educational). It was shortly after watching this video that I ditched the `$A`-style format for cell addressing and used the more sensible `R1C1`-style addressing (see at about the 8-1/2 minute mark but be sure to watch the whole thing).